# Se envia correctamente los datos a la BD de phpMyAdmin, pero success: function de Ajax muestra la condicional incorrecta (el else), en vez del if

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

Este es mi script de JavaScript. Gracias a Ajax, se envían los datos hacia el servidor de phpMyAdmin correctamente pero muestra en el login del sistema la alerta equivocada(revisar las condicionales en success: function de Ajax).

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    /* esta es la estructura por defecto para utilizar codigo jQuery */
    $(document).ready(function(){
    /* al hacer clic en el boton de submit */
    $('#buttonSubmit').click(function(){
    /* se guardan los datos del form en una variable dado el id del form, 
    codificar un conjunto de elementos de formulario como una cadena para el envío. */
    var datos=$('#idForm').serialize();
    /* estructura basica de ajax */
        $.ajax({
          /*  elementos de ajax */
          type:"POST",
          url:"login.php", 
          data:datos, 
          /* realiza un echo de php y lo envia en una variable */
          success: function(r){
            if(r){
            alert("Agregado con exito");
            }else{
            alert("Fallo el server");
            }
          }
          });
          /* retorna false*/
          return false;
        });
    });

  </script> /* se finaliza mi script en javascript*/
```

Aquí está mi Código php. Conecto con la base de datos de phpMyAdmin localmente en mi laptop.

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost"); /* Edit to connect to remote database */
define("DB_NAME", "autenticacion"); /* Edit to change database name */
define("DB_USER", "aran"); /* Edit to change database user */
define("DB_PASS", "c32b42H*"); /* Edit to change database user password */

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$connection->set_charset("utf8");


$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$contraseña = $_POST["password"];

$query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO GestionAcademica SET correo = '$correo', fullName= '$nombre', contraseña = '$contraseña'";
mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_user);

?>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código de `login.php`.

Comment: Supongo que te la r es true o false prueba r == "true"

Comment: @A.Cedano la verdad q no tengo idea de cómo editarlo. Me resulta complicada la edición de mis preguntas en StackOverflow :(

Comment: @JorgeLuis al poner if(r) ya pregunto que si es verdadera. De todas formas, comparé con ==true y nada :(

Comment: Sólo tienes que: 1. Copiar el código que tienes escrito en tu IDE. 2. Pegar ese código aquí. Y, una vez pegado, seleccionar todo el bloque de código y hacer click en el símbolo **`{ }`** (eso es para indentar el código). 3. Pulsar en `Guardar Edición`.  Si no entiendes el punto 2, pega el código sin indentar y mediante una edición lo arreglaremos. No es tan complicado como crees.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya puse el código php bien. Es que a veces me salen símbolos extraños en el panel de edición y no se cómo acomodarlo todo.

Comment: r es lo que retorno tu php? entonces, r no es un booleano... es todo un json con un conjunto de datos... fijate en tu codigo, de hacer un console.log de r, y vas a ver que nada que ver con lo que pensas que tiene.. porque pensas que r es un booleano? es mas.. tu codigo de php, no devuelve nada dentro de data (que es lo que viene en el json como respuesta de tu php)...

Comment: No estás devolviendo ninguna respuesta desde `login.php`, por eso el `if` entra en la parte del `else`.

Comment: @gbianchi ya me di cuenta. El problema es que me estuve guiando por un tutorial y no me percaté que se retornaba todo por un echo en php. Al hacerlo, pues me entró correctamente al if. Gracias :)

Comment: @A.Cedano ya me di cuenta. Al guiarme por un tutorial que estaba siguiendo, me di cuenta que se retorna el mysqli_query en un echo y así creo que se le da un retorno hacia ajax.                                   
    echo mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_user);    Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás devolviendo ninguna respuesta desde `login.php`, por eso el `if` entra en la parte del `else`.

Sugiero dos pequeños cambios, para que trabajemos con un JSON.

En la petición Ajax, agregaremos un `dataType`, y en la comprobación del `success` veremos si la respuesta del servidor tiene o no una clave `msg`, si no la tiene, tendrá una clave `error`:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    /* esta es la estructura por defecto para utilizar codigo jQuery */
    $(document).ready(function(){
    /* al hacer clic en el boton de submit */
    $('#buttonSubmit').click(function(){
    /* se guardan los datos del form en una variable dado el id del form, 
    codificar un conjunto de elementos de formulario como una cadena para el envío. */
    var datos=$('#idForm').serialize();
    /* estructura basica de ajax */
        $.ajax({
          /*  elementos de ajax */
          type:"POST",
          url:"login.php", 
          dataType:"json",
          data:datos, 
          /* realiza un echo de php y lo envia en una variable */
          success: function(r){
            if(r.msg){
                alert(r.msg);
            }else{
                alert(r.error);
            }
          }
          });
          /* retorna false*/
          return false;
        });
    });

  </script> /* se finaliza mi script en javascript*/
```

Y en PHP, emite una respuesta que será recibida por el cliente. Haremos algunas comprobaciones:

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost"); /* Edit to connect to remote database */
define("DB_NAME", "autenticacion"); /* Edit to change database name */
define("DB_USER", "aran"); /* Edit to change database user */
define("DB_PASS", "c32b42H*"); /* Edit to change database user password */

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$connection->set_charset("utf8");

$json=array();
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$contraseña = $_POST["password"];

$query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO GestionAcademica SET correo = '$correo', fullName= '$nombre', contraseña = '$contraseña'";
if (mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_user)) {
    $num=mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
    $msg = ($num > 0) ? sprintf("Filas insertadas: %d",$num) : "No se insertaron filas";
    $json['msg']=$msg;
} else {
    $json['error']='Error en la consulta';
}
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

En PHP he agregado algunas comprobaciones mínimas, aunque faltan más cosas por verificar, como el estado de las variables del POST, el estado de la conexión, etc. Y, convendría también que no uses variables con `ñ` o carácteres especiales. Otro problema ahí es la seguridad, deberías usar consultas preparadas, pero no nos metamos con eso ahora... Modificando el código así debería funcionar. Cuando funcione, corrige lo que te acabo de decir para que tengas un código seguro y maduro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el código y la ayuda compartida. Voy a probar tu código y te mantengo al tanto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, resolvió el problema adecuadamente. A que te refieres con consultas preparadas ?

Comment: @Aran son consultas en las que pones marcadores en vez de los datos, los cuales se mandan por otra vía, para evitar lo que se conoce como *inyección SQL*. Cuando puedas lee sobre el tema, aquí hay varias preguntas que tratan de eso y en la red abundan artículos sobre ello.

Comment: me hago una idea... Gracias por todo!

Comment: @Aran me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer este simple cambio

dado que en tu codigo solo se evalua si llega o no algo

pero como no tienes ningun echo resive string vacio que se toma como false.

```
if(mysqli_query($connection, $query_insert_user)){
 // esto enviare 1 string 1 que se tomara como true
 echo 1;
}else{
 // esto enviara 1 string 0 que se tomara como false
 echo 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)